# Python Machine Learning - Figure out Mathematical Equation for expected outcome

Tags: python

Maybe I don't want machine learning and I might just be looking for a term to find some working examples, Basically, I have 'x' values and I want to figure out what formula(s) have a greater than 75% success rate overall the values given.

Let's say, for example, I have these values

1  2  3 6
7  9  1 63
10 1  2 20
9  3  3 33

What I'm trying to develop is an algorithm that will basically permiuntate all values in [0],[1],[2] by all basic math functions ( + / * - )  and end up with [3].  So I know if the first 3 values are multiplied [0]*[1]*[2] = [3] and since [3] fails it has hit my 75% rate.

Comment: This isn't an ML problem. Just test all possible equations that use those values (there aren't many for such short equations), then count.

Comment: Do you want each value in the list permuted or are you happy with just combinations? So, for example, do you want the product of every first element in lists 1, 2 and 3 to match any element in list 4, or do you want the product of any of the items in list 1 to match any in 4. As Arya states, this isn't an ML problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually feels like a rare reasonable use for `eval`:

```
from itertools import product
from statistics import mean
from typing import Sequence


def build_expression(ops: Sequence[str], values: Sequence[int]) -> str:
    return " ".join(
        c for t in zip(map(str, values), ops) for c in t
    ) + " " + str(values[-1])


def apply_ops(ops: Sequence[str], values: Sequence[int]) -> int:
    """apply_ops(['+', '-'], [1, 2, 3]) == 1 + 2 - 3"""
    assert len(ops) + 1 == len(values)
    return eval(build_expression(ops, values))


def score_op_accuracy(
    ops: Sequence[str],
    data: Sequence[Sequence[int]]
) -> float:
    assert all(len(ops) + 2 == len(values) for values in data)
    return mean(
        100.0
        if apply_ops(ops, values[:-1]) == values[-1] else
        0.0
        for values in data
    )


data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 6],
    [7, 9, 1, 63],
    [10, 1, 2, 20],
    [9, 3, 3, 33],
]
possible_ops = list(product(*([list("+-*/%")] * 2)))
valid_ops = [
    ops for ops in possible_ops if score_op_accuracy(ops, data) >= 75.0
]
for ops in valid_ops:
    for values in data:
        left = values[:-1]
        right = values[-1]
        result = apply_ops(ops, left)
        equals = "==" if right == result else "!="
        print(f"{build_expression(ops, left)} {equals} {result}")
    print("-" * 20)
```

prints:

```
1 * 2 * 3 == 6
7 * 9 * 1 == 63
10 * 1 * 2 == 20
9 * 3 * 3 != 81
--------------------
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I'm looking for!  I wonder, do you have an example if you don't know the order or data and only new the end result?

Comment: Add in `itertools.permutations` to try scrambling the data up different ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
def plus(x,y):
    return x+y
def minus(x,y):
    return x-y
def times_by(x,y):
    return x*y
def divided_by(x,y):
    return x/y

def find_solution(l):
    x,y,z,targ = l

    for func1 in [plus, minus, times_by, divided_by]:
        for func2 in [plus, minus, times_by, divided_by]:
            if func2(func1(x,y), z) == targ :
                print(f'({x} {func1.__name__} {y}) {func2.__name__} {z} = {targ}')
            if func1(x, func2(y,z)) == targ:
                print(f'{x} {func1.__name__} ({y} {func2.__name__} {z}) = {targ}')

find_solution([7, 9, 1, 63])
```

output:

```
(7 times_by 9) times_by 1 = 63
7 times_by (9 times_by 1) = 63
(7 times_by 9) divided_by 1 = 63
7 times_by (9 divided_by 1) = 63
```

I'll leave some edge cases and errors (dividing by zero, notably) to you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you want to do, but here's what I came up with

df

```
0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   6
1   7   9   1   63
2   10  1   2   20
3   9   3   3   33
```

Code

```
from itertools import permutations

for index, data in df.iterrows():
    t = []
    for p in permutations(data[0:3]):
        t.extend([
            p[0] + p[1] + p[2],
            p[0] - p[1] - p[2],
            p[0] / p[1] / p[2],
            p[0] * p[1] * p[2]])

    if np.mean([x==data[3] for x in t[0::4]]) >=.75:
        print(data.values, 'sum')
    elif np.mean([x==data[3] for x in t[1::4]]) >=.75:
        print(data.values, 'subtract')
    elif np.mean([x==data[3] for x in t[2::4]]) >=.75:
        print(data.values, 'divide')
    elif np.mean([x==data[3] for x in t[4::4]]) >=.75:
        print(data.values, 'multiply')
```

Output

```
[1 2 3 6] sum
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe a linear regression problem. Through linear regression, you can get a formula similar to the following:

```
y = a * x1 + b * x2 + c * x3 + d
```

a, b, c and d are the parameters that need to be learned.

First, copy your data to `test.txt`:

Then, read and train:

```py
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Read data to a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None, sep=' ')
df.columns = list('ABCD')

# Train a linear regression model
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['A', 'B', 'C']], df['D'])

# Get score, i.e. accuracy
print(reg.score(df[['A', 'B', 'C']], df['D']))  # 1.0

# Get model's prediction
print(reg.predict(df[['A', 'B', 'C']]))  # [ 6. 63. 20. 33.]

# Get parameters
print(reg.coef_, reg.intercept_)  # [2.54761905 6.61904762 2.30952381] -16.71428571428573
```

So, the final formula is:

```
y = 2.54761905 * x1 + 6.61904762 * x2 + 2.30952381 * x3 - 16.71428571428573
```

If you have more data, this model will be more generalized.